# Handling array paramter in html_anchor function of Twig in FuelPHP

Tags: php, twig, fuelphp

I am converting the PHP based template to TWIG based template in FuelPHP.

```
echo Html::anchor('categories/create', 'Add', array('class' => 'btn'));
```

I found out with some help that the equivalent tag for TWIG is html_anchor which works fine. But as in this case, there is an third parameter passed as an array. How that can be converted for TWIG?

I tried the below found 2 lines and both failed with error so I assume its not the correct way.

```
{{ html_anchor('categories/create', 'Add', array('class' => 'btn')) }}
```

Twig arrays has [] format, so I tried this too.

```
{{ html_anchor('categories/create', 'Add', ['class' : 'btn']) }}
```

What's the correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you define an associative array in twig:

```
{{ html_anchor('categories/create', 'Add', { 'class': 'btn' }) }}
```